# How to display an embedded document in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Newbie question here. I am using mongoid, rails 3.2 and nested_form for my nested forms.

I have a `Profile` model that `embeds_many :services`. I'm using a nested form and have been able to successfully save it to my db. However, I can't figuer out how to display the embeded documents on my page. This seems like the easiest piece of the puzzle. Below is what my db looks like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "507d6fc757299e4a0c000002" ),
  "biz_name" : "Shop Co",
  "services" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "508c066a57299ef138000008" ),
      "s_and_p_service_description" : "what a great pie",
      "s_and_p_service_title" : "Pie" }, 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "508c079357299ef138000009" ),
      "s_and_p_service_title" : "Fruit",
      "s_and_p_service_description" : "what a great fruit" } ],
  "updated_at" : Date( 1351354259379 ),
  "user_id" : ObjectId( "507d6fc757299e4a0c000001" ) 
}
```

I thought something like this would have done it in:

```
<% @profile.services.each do |service| %>                           
    <%= @profile.services.s_and_p_service_title %>
<% end %>
```

but I get the follow error:

```
undefined method `s_and_p_service_title' for #<Array:0x007fa22a643c18>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you copy/pasted a little bit too much there. Try this:

```
<% @profile.services.each do |service| %>                           
    <%= service.s_and_p_service_title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You were to quick. I have to let a few more minutes go by before I can accept it. I will accept it as soon as I can. ;)